# Maruti Suzuki Swift Check Engine Light On And Engine Coolant Temperature Needle stay at 'C'

Tags: coolant, obd-ii, cel

My Swift VXI has developed a condition. I have started to see the check-engine light on and the Engine Coolant Temperature Needle stays at 'C' after starting the engine. Engine gives a growling sound. What could be the reason?

This problem occurred after i connected the OBD-II device in my car and used an Android app to check different gauges.

Answer (score 1):

**What I tried?**

I have recently (today) tested OBD II on my Maruti Suzuki WagonR made in mid 2013. I'm using some cheap quality Bluetooth BT connector (borrowed from friend) with Free version of Torque (OBD scanner/reader Android app). Live readings while driving car were good. Pretty much valid. No issues so far. I plugout the connector while leaving car as it consumes battery and it broadcast BT pairing. BT pairing is pretty easy for anyone. 
Online seach indicates, any vehicle made after April'2013 is OBD II compliance.

**Need more details from you:**

1. What is manufacturing month year of your MS Swift Petrol car? You can figure it out from VIN number in case you are not very sure. As old vehicles are not supproted for OBD II, it might cause unknown issue. Remote possibility.
2. What Android app you tried and how? Connection type, wifi or Bluetooth or direct cable?
3. Checking gauges is fine, it's just read only data. You can not change any config on PCB using those android apps. I don't think, it's really due gauge.
4. Did you tried removing OBD connector/scanner and start the engine? Also try to send if you have any log report of OBD scanner. Any errors codes reported by app? It's possible that app isn't getting Coolent temparatur and Engine light details. See for error codes if any.

I see, your question is pretty fresh. Did you still face issue or seen mechanic or dealer? MS is pretty good in service, try them. I guess, they do attach OBD while doing servicing but they exactly know what they do.

Let me know with more details.